# The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable Selenium webdriver XPATH

Tags: selenium, variables, xpath, webdriver, variable-assignment

I am automating the web site using Selenium webdriver and below is the code, the code is failing with the error message

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable for identifying
>   the login field using the XPATH, I am using XPATH since the ID and
>   name are already failed and when I use the XPATH the below error
>   message is populated, please help to correct the code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class FirstClass {

    private static final String SeleniumWait = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
       "C:\\Users\\Documents\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("nav-link-accountList")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("signin")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);// 1 minute 
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("//*
        [@id="ap_email"]")));
        //chrome.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.id("//*      
        [@id="ap_email"]")).sendKeys("testtest@gmail.com");

        /*driver.findElement(By.id("ap_assword")).sendKeys("Teachme100$");
        driver.findElement(By.id("signInSubmit")).click();
        //driver.close();*/

        /*WebElement ap_email = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))



       .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("ap_email")));*/
    }

    public static String getSeleniumwait() {
        return SeleniumWait;
    }

}
```

Comment: The code with the error in Eclipse is      driver.findElement(By.id("//*[@id="ap_email"]")).sendKeys("testtest@gmail.com");            XPATH = "//*[@id="ap_email"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a typo. Could you change the double quote (") to single quote(')?

```
driver.findElement(By.id("//*[@id='ap_email']")).sendKeys("testtest@gmail.com");
```

Comment: Hi Buaban - Thank you for your updates, yes it's the double quotes of xpath I have changed to single quotes and By.xpath instead of By.id and it worked fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Rajkumar Your welcome. Can you click accept my answer so we can close this question?